# Can a camera affect the Quantum Entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, measurements

'*Spooky action at a distance*' is how Albert Einstein famously derided the concept of quantum entanglement, wherein objects can become linked and instantaneously influence one another. Entanglement is broken when the entangled particles de-cohere through interaction with the environment, for example, when a measurement is made.

My question is as follows. If we place camera in a room, does connection with that object in this room get broken? If not, then how we can vanquish Quantum Entanglement from a room?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A contact with a "classical" object is *measurement*, in quantum mechanical sense, and will cause the wave function collapse. Typically a camera would act as such an object... or, perhaps, it is more precise to say that the collapse/decoherence would be caused by the photons that scatter from the entangled objects towards the camera.

Comment: thanks..my means was for a ongoing measurement without shake that object